# Identify valid IP from a set of column values

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a column name ip_addr which contains both valid as well as invalid IP. I wish to subset only valid IP addresses in Teradata. Right now I'm using the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
EXECUTE
(
create multiset volatile table base as
(
select  distinct int_cust_ip_addr as ip_addr

from cm11_jan14
where int_cust_ip_addr like '%.%.%.%' 
) 
WITH  DATA PRIMARY INDEX(ip_addr) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
)
BY TERADATA;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TD14+ supports Regular Expressions, this returns **1** for a correct IP4 address:

```
where REGEXP_SIMILAR (int_cust_ip_addr, '^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$') = 1
```

For IP6 simply search for "regex ip6"